# prove that $uv'-vu'\neq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $u$, $v$, $u'$ and $v'$ be continuous. If between any two consecutive real root of $u$, there exists a real root of $v$, and between any two consecutive real roots of $v$, there lies a real root of $u$. Then prove that $uv'-vu'\neq 0$.

I have proved the converse easily using Mean Value Theorem, but having trouble with this proof. Please give me a solution, or at least a hint, or refute this by a counterexample.

Comment: Do you mean that the expression is not identically zero, or that it has no zeros? The latter is not true.

Comment: What you want to prove is that $uv' - vu'$ has no real root?

Comment: Are those roots simple, i.e., do the functions always change sign at the roots? Note that $(\arg(u+iv))'=\frac{uv'-u'v}{u^2+v^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the roots are simple, then considering the curve $z(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$ one finds that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\arg z(t)=Im\left(\frac{z'(t)}{z(t)}\right)=\frac{uv'-u'v}{u^2+v^2}
$$

The assumptions then mean that $z$ is never zero and that the curve of $z$ passes from quadrant to quadrant either always clockwise or always counter-clockwise crossing the axes perpendicularly.

It does however not prescribe what curls the curve traces inside the quadrants. It is thus possible, and quite easy to draw examples of it, that the angle temporarily moves backwards. At the local maxima and minima of the angle, the expression $uv'-u'v$ is zero.